# How to access Strong parameters from Model in Rails 4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

Let's suppose I have a customer controller with `strong_parameters` as follows:

```
def update
  @customer.update_attributes(customer_params)
end

private

def customer_params
  params.require(:customer).permit(:name, :age)
end
```

Now I want to access permitted parameters (name and age) from the `Customer` model. For example:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.some_method
    allowed_parameters = customer_params
  end
end
```

How can I access those parameters? How can I get `allowed_parameters = customer_params` from the Customer model?

Comment: Your code effectively writes them into the model. So typical attribute access applies. But I'm getting the feeling you want something else, try providing an example of how you'd expect that to look like.

Comment: I have updated my question, I think it is more clear now

Comment: Ah. So you want a list of **allowed attribute names**. Well... it's complicated. Where do you expect to get it from? Just write a whitelist somewhere? Infer from the table? Or what?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is unusual. Allowed attributes don't usually belong in the model. They are a controller concern, hence why Rails removed `attr_accessible` in favour of `strong_parameters`. If you need to protect attributes, ActiveRecord has [`attr_read_only`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ReadonlyAttributes/ClassMethods/attr_readonly).

If you want a central place to keep them, just add a constant in your model.

```
class Customer
  ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES = [:name, :role]

  def allowed_attributes
    ALLOWED_ATTRIBUTES
  end
end
```

Now you can do `User.allowed_attributes` from anywhere.

```
private

def customer_params
  params.require(:customer).permit(*User.allowed_attributes)
end
```

But this is not desirable in my opinion because allowed attributes should set in some context, like a user role, or an access level, etc...